# Correlation among user actions and independent variable in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am new here and have no idea on how to approach this problem. Many thanks in advance

I have a DB that looks like these (with 100k rows)

```
Name        action                      date of action      independent variable
Subject a   “clickVideo1, openEmail2”   “1/1/2017,1/1/2018” 10,000
Subject b   “read blog 3”               “2/2/2019”          5,000
```

The problem as I see it is that:

First I need to separate the actions into columns (I have hundreds of actions and users have between 0 and 300 actions)

Second I need to see if there is a correlation with some of the actions vs my independent variable.

Comment: A (Pearson, Spearman, Kendall) correlation coefficient only makes sense between two continuous variables. Your data is not continuous. If you’re interested in characterising the dependence of a categorical on a continuous variable, the most classic approach is a one-way ANOVA. See e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/correlation-coefficient-for-non-dichotomous-nominal-variable-and-ordinal-numeric) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25229/correlation-between-dichotomous-and-continuous-variable)

Comment: [...] Also from [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/pearsons-or-spearmans-correlation-with-non-normal-data): *"Pearson's correlation is a measure of the linear relationship between **two continuous random variables**. It does not assume normality although it does assume finite variances and finite covariance. [...] Spearman's correlation applies to ranks and so provides a measure of a monotonic relationship between **two continuous random variables**."* (bold face is mine).

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate the actions you should check out the function `strsplit()` and to compute the correlation between two variables a good option is the function `cor()`

Comment: It is not working since the names of the columns make no sence and have no order at all